# Unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the step size below the smallest value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, computer-science, matlab

I am solving system of Differential-Algebraic using ODE15s MATLAB, and this is a segment of my code

```
 options = odeset('Mass',M,'RelTol',1e-3,...,
                 'Vectorized','off','MaxStep',1e-4);

  tspan = [0 50];

  [t,y] = ode15s(@fs,tspan,y0,options);
```

But I got this error message

"Unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the step size below the smallest value allowed (5.551115e-17) at time t."

But I did not understand the message, How can I fix it? I think I should choose fit values for step size and tolerance error, Any advises?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's impossible to help you with incomplete, un-runnable code. The first thing to check is that you have no errors or typos in your function `fs` and mass matrix. And have you tried specifying `tspan = [0 500];` to let the solver choose the output points?

Comment: I do not think that i have any mistake in fs or M, I did not include them because they are big and complicated.
I used  tspan = [0 500] but no results.

Comment: Actually I got the some results just for time 0 to time 2 after that I got the error message.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your solution is encountering a singularity of some sort, or it could be that you have a "stiff" system that is difficult for  numerical methods to handle. You might want to see what it's doing just before the time where the error occurs.  Is it going off to infinity or oscillating wildly?  Is it approaching a place where the equations become undefined?  Does this reflect possible behaviour in the actual system you're trying to model, or is it an artifact of the numerical method?

Comment: Thank you doctor for your reply.
Actually this problem was solved before numerically in another software and I am trying to solve it by ode15s. so I do not think there is a singularity or stiffness.

Comment: Actually most of ode15s examples set 'Vectorized','on', but in my code I set 'off'. do you think this might make a problem?

Comment: There are all sorts of scenarios that could explain why one software encounters difficulties while another doesn't.  Having few clues about the nature of the actual problem, it's impossible to do more than speculate.  From a quick look at the documentation, it doesn't look like Vectorized should make any difference except in the efficiency of the solution process.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this means that the graph of the function has gotten so steep that MATLAB can't graph it. What could this imply? A singularity at that point.

Perhaps use the ode23t function instead?

Documentation can be found here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode23t.html

Comment: I used ode23t but no results.